# How to insert values in another table in controller joomla

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla 3.1.1 and joomshopping. i need to insert values in another table at same time when user register on website. In user controller i need to insert values in my custom table. can i use a direct insert query in my controller file. this is function in controller file to register user. Where i can put my code to insert data in another table.

```
 function registersave(){
    JSession::checkToken() or jexit(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
    $jshopConfig = JSFactory::getConfig();
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users');
    $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $lang->load('com_users');
    $post = JRequest::get('post');
    JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
    $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
    $res = $dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer',$post['recaptcha_response_field']);

    if(!$res[0]){
        JError::raiseWarning('','Invalid Captcha');
        $this->setRedirect("index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=user&task=register",'','',$jshopConfig->use_ssl);

    }
    else
    {
        JPluginHelper::importPlugin('jshoppingcheckout');
        $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();

        if ($params->get('allowUserRegistration')==0){
            JError::raiseError( 403, JText::_('Access Forbidden'));
            return;
        }

        $usergroup = JTable::getInstance('usergroup', 'jshop');
        $default_usergroup = $usergroup->getDefaultUsergroup();
         if (!$_POST["id"]){

    }
        $post['username'] = $post['u_name'];
        $post['password2'] = $post['password_2'];
        //$post['name'] = $post['f_name'].' '.$post['l_name'];

        $post['mailing_list'] = $post['mailing_list'];

        $hear = '';

        $post['where_did_you_purchase'] = $post['where_did_you_purchase'];

        $post['ages_of_your_children'] = $agesofchilderen;
        $post['comments_or_suggestions'] = $post['comments_or_suggestions'];
        $post['vehicle_2'] = $post['vehicle_2_model'].'-'.$post['vehicle_2_year'];

        if ($post['birthday']) $post['birthday'] = getJsDateDB($post['birthday'], $jshopConfig->field_birthday_format);

        $dispatcher->trigger('onBeforeRegister', array(&$post, &$default_usergroup));

        $row = JTable::getInstance('userShop', 'jshop');
        $row->bind($post);
        $row->usergroup_id = $default_usergroup;
        $row->password = $post['password'];
        $row->password2 = $post['password2'];

        if (!$row->check("register")){
            JError::raiseWarning('', $row->getError());
            $this->setRedirect(SEFLink("index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=user&task=register",1,1, $jshopConfig->use_ssl));
            return 0;
        }


        $user = new JUser;
        $data = array();
        $data['groups'][] = $params->get('new_usertype', 2);
        $data['email'] = JRequest::getVar("email");
        $data['password'] = JRequest::getVar("password");
        $data['password2'] = JRequest::getVar("password_2");
        //$data['name'] = $post['f_name'].' '.$post['l_name'];
        $data['username'] = JRequest::getVar("u_name");
        $useractivation = $params->get('useractivation');
        $sendpassword = $params->get('sendpassword', 1);

        if (($useractivation == 1) || ($useractivation == 2)) {
            jimport('joomla.user.helper');
            $data['activation'] = JApplication::getHash(JUserHelper::genRandomPassword());
            $data['block'] = 1;
        }

        //echo $row->getTableName();

        //print_r($row);

        //die("kkk");

        $user->bind($data);
        $user->save();
        $row->user_id = $user->id;
        unset($row->password);
        unset($row->password2);
        if (!$db->insertObject($row->getTableName(), $row, $row->getKeyName())){
            JError::raiseWarning('', "Error insert in table ".$row->getTableName());
            $this->setRedirect(SEFLink("index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=user&task=register",1,1,$jshopConfig->use_ssl));
            return 0;
        }







    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Please do not edit Joomla core files.

If you need to add register data on your custom table the create a `User Plugin`.
Joomla provides lot of [plugin events](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) in your case you can use `onUserAfterSave`. event

Create a [User plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterSave) with  `onUserAfterSave` event then simply use the [Joomla DB](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase) library to your custom table entries.

Hope it helps..

Comment: This is joomshopping user registration file. Is there any another solution without plugin?

Comment: In any cart registration the user will registered to normal Joomla user table to so check the functions that triggering normal Joomla user table entry use the same method for your plugin. Other than plugin there is no standard way to do this. You can Edit the core files just add custom query in user register success case.

Comment: when a user register from website then there is no entry in joomla default table. there is a table joomshopping users. can i use model function and then call it in controller?

Comment: normally it should check `#__users` table. you can use the model function call from controller.

Comment: can you please help me that how i can call a modle function in controller. There is no model for this controller.

Comment: check this for calling a [model](http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JController/getModel)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help but I have used $db->insertObject to insert record in different table. 


    $records = new stdClass;
    $records->id = NULL;
    $records->submitted = $submitted;
    $records->form = $formId;
    $records->title = $your_title_string;
    $records->name = $Name;
    $db->insertObject($tableName, $records, 'id');